# Eu consigo colocar uma background-image em uma section?

Tags: html, css, background-image

Criei uma `section` no meu HTML e no CSS coloquei:

```
section{
    background-image: url(../img/bkg2.jpg);
}
```

Porém a imagem não aparece. E verifiquei o caminho e está correto.

Comment: Isso não é muito correto mas tenta colocar esse pedaço do seu css e dentro da <head> com a tag <style> e ver se vai.

Comment: Abra o console e veja se tem algum erro

Answer (score 1):

Com certeza!

```css
    section {
     background-image: url("https://static.pexels.com/photos/294674/pexels-photo-294674.jpeg");
        width: 100%;
        height: 500px;
    }
```

```html
<section></section>
```

**A imagem aparece, mas o problema está nas dimensões da sua section!**

Recomendo não fazer uso de CSS generalizando elementos assim, use `Class` e `ID`. Pois todas as suas sections ficarão iguais.

Answer (score 0):

```
header#cabecalho {
    border-bottom: 1px #606060 solid;
    height: 150px;
    background: url("../_imagens/glass-logo-peq.jpg") no-repeat 0px 80px;
}
```

ola, talvez atribuir uma id para uma área especifica da sua section ajude.

Espero ter ajudado! =D.

Comment: Ajudou sim, eu tinha esquecido o height. Muito Obrigada <3